# Compiling via Perl Packager including libraries?

Tags: perl, compilation, packager, perl-packager

I recently compiled a perl script using "pp" (Perl Packager) on an x86 linux box running Manjaro.  I had someone test it on their x86 Debian 10 box, but it wouldn't run.

He said that since Libperl.so has a dependence on glibc v2.29. Since his OS release only allows up to a v2.28, that it's preventing it from executing.

Is there a way for me to compile my script with my version of the libraries so it will run on any x86 linux machine?

I ran the following command to compile my code:

```
pp -o oag1025 oag1025.pl
```

I tried using some of the options outlined here, but I couldn't get anywhere:

http://perl.mines-albi.fr/perl5.8.5/site_perl/5.8.5/pp.html

Comment: Please be more specific about what options you have tried, and list them out instead of posting a link.

Comment: You could try link your code [statically](https://cs-fundamentals.com/tech-interview/c/difference-between-static-and-dynamic-linking.php) instead of dynamically, but see also [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0513/) discussion for a similar problem in Python.

Comment: From what I read, I think it's statically linked by default, but honestly I don't know the difference.